# Extend multiple interface in TypeScript with OR condition

Tags: node.js, typescript, generics, interface, typescript-generics

I Have three interface

```
inteface A {
    name: string
    id: number
    address: string
    details : object
}

   inteface B {
        name: string
        id: string
        address: string
        details : string
        age: number
    }



inteface C {
        name: string
        id: string
        address: object
        details : object
        age: number
        height: number
    }
```

**YES You noticed right different interfaces may have different types with the common fields**
like **interface A** have `id: number` but **B** have `id: string`

Now I have a common interface

```
interface Common {
   group: string
   class: string
}
```

Now I have a function which is accepting parameter Object which will definitely have **interface Common** fields but may have fields of one of the interfaces A, B, and C

I want to use the `Common` which will extend either of the interface in it `A`, `B`, and `C`

```
function insert(params: Common){
   ....
}
```

Now I thought of using generic but I failed in doing what I want,
So can someone tell me how can I use this with generics and get what I wanted if it can be done through generic,

If not suggest me another method to do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this:

```js
type ABC = A | B | C

function insert(params: Common & ABC): {
  ...
}
```

Comment: OK. But, here is my example:
export interface A {
  type: string;
  svc: string;
}
export interface B {
  id: string;
}
export type AB = A | B;
func(config: AB) {
    if (config.type ) {
      ...
    }
This brings me an TS error:
TS2339: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'AB'.   Property 'type' does not exist on type 'B'.

Comment: @westor did you fix this problem? I have the same issue. It just let me load a property which is all interface or types, the other are no same can't load, and I get `type' does not exist `

Comment: @ShahryarTavakkoli yes -  you have do do this: if ('type' in config) {... }